# Chrome opening extensions page when a new tab is opened

Tags: google-chrome

I installed a [bookmark manager chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-manager-speed-di/pdcohkhhjbifkmpakaiopnllnddofbbn?hl=en) and found that on every new tab, the extension opens itself. I checked chrome settings and found this:

[image]

I am not able to figure it out how can I get blank page when I open a new tab. What I am missing?

Comment: You might need to click on "Turn off" to the right of the blue link.

Comment: "Turn off" disables the extension.

Answer (score 0):

In the Papaly Bookmark Manager's Speed Dial extensions' settings, there is "Extension options" link which allows to disable this new tab page:

[image]